# Can I permanently disable showing debug tool window on debug app (shift + f9)?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

If I run app by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> (debug app) on Idea/Android Studio, I always see showing debug tool window.

But I do not want to see this window. Definitely, I can show/hide it by shortcut.
But then, I need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> each time.

Is there any way to disable showing the tool window permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Debug Configurations** -> untick **'Activate tool window'** under **Before launch** section.

[image]

Comment: Hm, strange. I have unchecked this checkbox, but anyway see tool window on start.

Comment: @YShinkarev very strange, this worked for me 100%. Please check whether you are editing the correct config. :)) This is supposed to work.

Comment: @YShinkarev couldn't you still sort this out??

Comment: I do not remember, what's I did, but now all work properly and window do not showen.